# for loop not traversed after the first time - Python

Tags: python, regex, for-loop

I'm trying to ignore the urls that are blacklisted from my search. 'ltp_block' contains the data which contain different urls.

```
p = re.compile('href="(.*?)" rel="nofollow"')
url = "http://www.****.**" + p.findall(current)[0]

r = requests.get(url)
```

The above code is used to fetch different urls from 'ltp_block'. r.url defines the url in loop when called for.

```
for each_row in blacklist:
    if(re.findall('\\b'+each_row[0]+'\\b', r.url, flags=re.IGNORECASE) != []):
        print "found"
```

**QUESTION** - Above 'for' loop works only ONCE. When 'check' becomes 1 OR the main loop chooses another url this second 'for' loop is simply skipped like it doesn't exist. Why ?

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('test.db')
c = conn.cursor()
blacklist = c.execute("SELECT `name` FROM `blacklist`")
check = 0
for row in ltp_block:

        p = re.compile('versan')
        current = ltp_block[check]
        if(p.findall(current) != []):
            p = re.compile('price=(.*?)&')
            ltp = p.findall(current)[0]
            del p
        else:
            p = re.compile('Gesa: (.*?) &')
            ltp = p.findall(current)[0]
            del p

        p = re.compile('href="(.*?)" rel="nofollow"')
        url = "http://www.****.**" + p.findall(current)[0]

        r = requests.get(url)

        for each_row in blacklist:
            if(re.findall('\\b'+each_row[0]+'\\b', r.url, flags=re.IGNORECASE) != []):
                print "found"

        check = check + 1
```

Answer -

I had to recompile blacklist = c.execute("SELECT `name` FROM `blacklist`") each time

I placed it in the main 'for' loop and everything is working now

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "misbehaves"? Does it not run at all? Does it throw an error? Have you tried the simplest of debugging techniques: printing intermediate values to see if they are what you expect?

Comment: It is skipped like it doesn't exist. Edited

Comment: Note that counting in a loop in Python is bad style, use ``enumerate()`` instead.

Comment: You don't show where `blacklist` comes from, but I'll guess it's an opened file.  Once you read a whole file, the file is positioned at EOF, and reading more will never get you more.  Also, why the `del p`?  And why compile your regexes each time like that?

Comment: Its coming from a database. del p , because i was trying various things. I complile my regexes like that because this is my first application in Python and the tutorial i learnt from showed me to compile it this way.

Answer (score 3):

`c.execute` is returning an iterator. Iterators can only be iterated over once. As a simpler example, try this:

```
numbers = (x for x in xrange(10))  # a simple iterator

for number in numbers:
     print number

print "Repeat"

for number in numbers:
     print number
```

Only the first loop gives any output, as the iterator is exhausted and empty at the start of the second. Compare that with:

```
numbers = (x for x in xrange(10))
numbers = list(numbers)  # turn the iterator into a list

for number in numbers:
     print number

print "Repeat"

for number in numbers:
     print number
```

Which works as expected. In your case, you want:

```
blacklist = list(c.execute("SELECT `name` FROM `blacklist`"))
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way for a for loop to be "simply skipped like it doesn't exist" is if there is nothing to iterate over. If that is truly the case, the only explanation is that `blacklist` is empty. There simply is no other explanation if what you report is true.

Such a thing is very easy to prove. Add a print statement immediately before the loop, and print out the value of `blacklist`:

```
print "blacklist:", blacklist
for each_row in blacklist:
    ...
```

Comment: Nope blacklist is never empty. I debugged it too.

Comment: If `blacklist` is not empty, than your assertion that the loop isn't running is false. The loop is running, but the code inside the loop isn't doing what you expect. If `blacklist` is iterable and non-empty, the loop will run.

Comment: Yes you are right. I found the answer, i placed the  blacklist = c.execute("SELECT `name` FROM `blacklist`") in the main loop and its working. However that makes me curious, im not assigning blacklist to anything else, then why do i have to put in the main 'for' loop for it to work

Comment: @Nuv:  Because the inner for-loop consumes the entire iterator.  Once it reaches the end of the results it won't iterate again from the beginning.  Running a query repeatedly inside a loop will be bad for performance.  If you can, cache the results in a list before your outer loop: `blacklist = list(c.execute("SELECT `name` FROM `blacklist`"))`.

Comment: @StevenRumbalski: Perfect. I used your method and its still working without hindering the performance.